# How to add table dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add table row dynamically. I tried with online solution but no luck 
My code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 var index = 2;
 var chr = 68;
    function insertRow(){
                var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
                var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
                var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
                var t1=document.createElement("input");
                 t1.setAttribute('name', "sigID"+index);
                    t1.setAttribute('value',  char(chr));
                    t1.setAttribute('size', 10);
                    cell1.appendChild(t1);
                var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
                var t2=document.createElement("input");
                 t2.setAttribute("type","text");
                 t2.setAttribute('name',"pattern"+index);
                    t2.setAttribute('size',10);
                    t2.setAttribute('colspan',2);
                    cell2.appendChild(t2);
          index++;
          chr++;

    }
 </script>
```

I have added one default row in HTML and then on clicking add I want to add row as per the need.
HTML Page:

```html
<table id="myTable" style="margin-left:201px;">
  <tr>
    <th>SigID</th>
    <th colspan="2">Patterns</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      {!!Form::text('sigID1','A',array('size'=>'5'))!!}
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      {!!Form::text('pattern1','',array('size'=>'102'))!!}
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="insertRow()" value="Add">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please let me know what is wrong in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
t1.setAttribute('value', char(chr));
```

to:

```
t1.setAttribute('value', String.fromCharCode(chr));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aasL9hg4/2/)

Comment: How to delete row if not required after addition(consider I have delete button there)

Comment: I would add an attribute to the row when it's created and target it when the delete button is clicked. But you might want to ask a new question if you don't work out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You have error in this line:

```
t1.setAttribute('value',  char(chr));
```

char is not Javascript function.

I assume you want this:

```
String.fromCharCode(chr)
```

Change the above line to this:

```
t1.setAttribute('value', String.fromCharCode(chr));
```

Answer (score 0):

I always find this site usefull, you can take a look at the given example
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp